# Inexplicable routing failures for a direct-bound orchestration receiving XmlDocument

Tags: biztalk, subscription, biztalk-2013, biztalk-orchestrations

I've created an orchestration project with a property schema that contains a boolean property `IsForFramework`. My aim is to have an orchestration receive all messages of type `System.Xml.XmlDocument` that have the aformentioned property promoted with a value of `true`.

This is part of the property schema:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Bakker.Framework.Orchestrations.Framework" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Bakker.Framework.Orchestrations.Framework" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo schema_type="property" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" /> 
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="IsForFramework" type="xs:boolean">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="9358dd05-92f7-4c84-8dc1-8427bea580a6" propSchFieldBase="MessageContextPropertyBase" /> 
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The filter expression on the receive shape:

```
(Bakker.Framework.Orchestrations.IsForFramework == true)
```

The actual subscription queried from the BizTalk console:

```
http://Bakker.Framework.Orchestrations.Framework.IsForFramework == True
```

In the **routing failure report context:**

```
IsForFramework  True    Promoted    http://Bakker.Framework.Orchestrations.Framework
```

I can't, for the life of me, figure out what could possible be going wrong here.

Comment: Does the message type match the message type the Orchestration is expecting? If you look in the Subscription for the Orchestration you will see that it is also looking for the correct message type.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf as mentioned in the title and the question body, the message type that the port and receive shape are configured for is `System.Xml.XmlDocument`. According to MSDN this is a type agnostic receive construction so any message will be routed to the orchestration, as long as the filter expression is matched.

Comment: No, that's only what you THINK you did.  Actually check the message context properties and the subscriptions.  I think you will find that they don't match.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf sorry but did you read my question? I put the subscription and the context property there exactly as they are and they do match exactly as far as I can see. When I replace the filter expression to use BTS.ReceivePortName, for example, it works perfectly. Also check the answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f04908d-f45f-4da7-b870-e9d07b67e529/binary-message-in-orchestration-binding-vs-direct?forum=biztalkgeneral)

Comment: Yes, I read your question, but the fact that you are getting a routing failure error is very indicative of the fact that the subscription of your Orchestration does not match the message context properties.  You have only shown us ONE of the context properties of the message and you have not shown us what the subscription of the Orchestration actually is.  Use BizTalk admin console and search for Subscriptions, find the Orchestration and look at it's subscription.  Double check that ALL of the subscription matches the context.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I put that in my question, it is the second-to-last "code block" preceded by the text "The actual subscription queried from the BizTalk console:". Don't know how much clearer I can get. As you can see it's only one property, and that property is promoted in the context of the message, and the value appears to be the same as what the subscription is looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64734/discussion-between-dijkgraaf-and-mdeschaepmeester).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion with MDeSchaepmeester it was determined that the underlying issue is that the Pipeline component that was promoting that context property and all the others it was promoting as strings, however this context property was defined as a Boolean in the Property Schema.
From [IBaseMessageContext.Promote Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.message.interop.ibasemessagecontext.promote%28v=bts.20%29.aspx) 
"If the types of the promoted properties do not match the values specified in subscription, the comparison fails and the message subscription does not occur. "

In this case you have two options

1) Either make sure that the object is cast to Boolean when you are promoting it.

2) Change the field type to String and change the filter expression to Bakker.Framework.Orchestrations.IsForFramework == "True" as suggested by Johns-305 (if they match type you won't get the error)

Answer (score 2):

Try for the Filter Expression:

Bakker.Framework.Orchestrations.IsForFramework == "True"

Single quotes might also work, the expression editor in the Orchestration Designer is different from the one in BT Admin.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't work. the error is `cannot implicitly convert type 'System.String' to 'System.Boolean'` when using double quotes and `'System.Char' to 'System.Boolean'` when using single quotes. I also get the first error when setting the value to `True` (without quotes, notice the capital letter). Additionally, I get `Illegal 'activate' predicate` in all 3 cases.

Comment: As it turns out it was half the correct answer. So a +1